# Visual studio is debugging an ASP.Net site I didn't ask it to!

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, debugging

I have an unusual problem with debugging a web application in visual studio 2008. I have a local debug build of the site running on my machine (via IIS 7), with VS2008 debugging it. If at this point I view the live site (which is a release build on a remote server) and make the live site crash, VS2008 leaps in and starts showing me where it's crashed and lets me step through the code etc as if I was debugging the debug build on my local machine.

Firstly, what is going on? This smells a bit like remote debugging to me, but the remote server is running a release build, and compilation debug is false in its web.config.
Secondly, does it constitute a security risk?
And finally, how do I stop it?

Comment: I'm not sure how important this is, but the remote server is on our network as well, but on a different domain. Its firewall is off as there's a proper hardware one between it and the outside world, but not one between me and it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what's happened is that the client side debugging has been enabled on the IIS website.  If that property is turned on then I'd turn that off and see if it takes care of your problem.

Comment: I don't think this is the case, as the client and server-side debugging options are only available for classic asp, and this is asp.net

Comment: Your right, I've been in classic ASP zone for too long.  Do you have the debug=true set in the web.config file??